# Can't connect to Cisco router's settings page

Tags: router, vpn, ip, subnet

Currently I have a 2 wire modem, and a Netgear WNDR3400. What I want to do is add a Cisco RV100W for its VPN features. Currently the Netgear router is connected to the modem via the WAN port. When I connect the new Cisco into the LAN port of router the Netgear a few problems show up.

When I connect to the Cisco router I get the same IP, subnet, default gateway as the Neatgear router. I am able to get on the Internet and surf the web, but when I put in the IP to get to the routers setting page I can only connect to the settings of pages the modem and Neatgear. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

If possible, I would remove the Netgear WNDR3400 from your setup and replace it with the Cisco RV100W. There should be no need for the Netgear (unless I'm missing something) and by adding this router you're confusing your setup.

It sounds like you connected a LAN port on the Cisco to a LAN port on the Netgear. The default address for the Cisco is probably 192.168.1.1. Either there's an IP address conflict, or you're on a different subnet (192.168.0.0) than your Cisco router, and now it is acting as a switch only.

---

If you want to keep both routers, I would still use the Cisco router as your "main" router and simply connect a LAN port on the Netgear to a LAN port on the Cisco.

First though, we're going to have to isolate this setup.

#### Remove the Cisco from the rest of your network

Plug your computer in to a LAN port on the Cisco. Don't plug in anything else. Now open a command prompt (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to open run box. Type `cmd`. Push enter.) Type the command `ipconfig /release` then `ipconfig /renew`. What this will do is release the address you received from DHCP earlier (likely coming from the Netgear router) and pick up an appropriate address from the Cisco router.

[image]

#### Configure the Cisco router

Try the default address `192.168.1.1` in your browser and see if it pulls up the page. If it doesn't, run the command `ipconfig` and figure out what the default gateway is, then input that.
You're kind of on your with the VPN configuration. I believe [this](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/routers/csbr/rv110w/administration/guide/rv110w_admin.pdf) is the manual you need.

#### Turn off DHCP on the Netgear

Now we need to configure the Netgear router so that it isn't serving DHCP (we don't want DHCP on the network twice...) Connect your PC to a LAN port on the Netgear, then /release and /renew (same as above.)

[image]

Now hop on your Netgear's configuration page and turn off DHCP. Take a look in the [manual](http://www.homedepot.com/catalog/pdfImages/0e/0ea87b67-2050-45ac-a89d-2cb253f22929.pdf) if you can't find it.

#### Give the Netgear a staic IP

Crack open the manual again and figure out how to give the Netgear a static IP address. **We're not interested in the Internet settings or WAN port**. We're trying to give it a static IP on the private network side.

Remember your Cisco's configuration page address? We need to give the Netgear an IP address in that subnet. If the address was `192.168.1.1` then `192.168.1.10` *should* work depending on the DHCP range the Cisco router is using.

#### Set up the network

[image]

Plug your computer and the Netgear in to the LAN ports of the Cisco. Connect the WAN port of the Cisco to the modem. Do another /release /renew. ***Now reboot all network devices!*** Ping around and see if everything is working, and you should be good to go.

Comment: The purpose of the netgear is, it has a usb port and i have 1TB hard drive connected to it. So i would really like to keep it, if possible.

Comment: @user200233 Had to make it hard didn't you? ;)

Answer (score 0):

Plug in the cisco directly to your PC, at this point you will not have internet access but you will be able to connect to the settings of the Cisco and configure it as needed.  If you do not know the default IP of the Cisco, make sure to look it up before disconnected from the internet.

Comment: i Have done this and i use that default address when Cisco is connected to the netgear and still does not work.